# typescript "in operator" does not work with string index

Tags: typescript

## Code

```js
const test = {
  a: 'b',
  c: 'd',
} as const;

const toPick: string = 'a';

if (toPick in test) {
  console.log(test[toPick]); // not "b" (Error)
}
```

without `as const` also Error

#### Error

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
> 'string'   can't be used to index type `'{ readonly a: "b"; readonly c: "d"; }'`.

> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string'   was found on
> type `'{ readonly a: "b"; readonly c: "d"; }'`.

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCm0YF4YG8CwAoGMCGAXDAOQBGxANNrsEcQCaXYC++EMokUA3Ntp0iggACgEtgAayLQATqLABzFCTzFeWbKIBmMABRCxkmPLiIoASnTUO4CCAA28AHT2QC-WYDaB8RIC65twwAPTBMGAgsABEpFEs2EA)

Comment: That's not how `in` narrowing works: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can infer it but then you need to remove explicit `string` type:

```js
const test = {
  a: 'b',
  c: 'd',
} as const;

const toPick = 'a';

if (toPick in test) {
  const x = test[toPick] // b
}
```

Because you have used `string` type for `a` and `test` does not have indexed property TS.

Most of the time you should not use explicit types. TS should infer it.

If you have used `string` explicit type by purpose, then you can use custom typeguard:

```js
const test = {
    a: 'b',
    c: 'd',
} as const;

const toPick: string = 'a';

const hasProperty = <Obj, Prop extends string>(obj: Obj, prop: Prop)
    : obj is Obj & Record<Prop, unknown> =>
    Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop);

if (hasProperty(test, toPick)) {
    test[toPick]
}
```

If you don't want to use custom typeguards and you can remove `as const`, you can provide explicit indexed type for `test`:

```js
const test: Record<string, string> = {
    a: 'b',
    c: 'd',
};

const toPick: string = 'a';


if (toPick in test) {
    test[toPick]
}
```

Comment: If `toPick` is going to have type `'a'` then there is no need to test if `toPick in test` at all; I think the point of the question is to have a variable of type `string` be narrowed to type `keyof typeof test` by this condition.

Comment: @kaya3 thanks for clarification, I made an update and have added several workarounds

Answer (score 1):

Typescript generally does not prove every provable property of your code, and is not trying to. The compiler does type narrowing, but only in specific circumstances according to specific rules, so it does not always narrow variables to the most specific type that a human would be able to deduce.

In this case, you are using the `in` operator, which Typescript [does have a type narrowing rule for](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing) - but that rule is for narrowing the type of the object, not the type of the property. According to the docs, this rule only applies when the property is a string literal, and the object has a union type.

Answer (score -1):

Narrowing is not going to work; it is meant to narrow the type of `test`. Use the refection API ?

```js
const test = {
  a: 'b',
  c: 'd',
} as const;
const toPick: string = 'a';

if (toPick in test) {
  console.log(Reflect.get(test,toPick)); 
}

//or

if (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(test).includes(toPick)) {
  console.log(Reflect.get(test,toPick));
}
```